# In rails, how do I run a column through javascript function to create data for new column?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have 20,000 records in a database with a column titled 'activity' that contains a long json object for each record. I also have a javascript function that will parse thorough the 'activity' json object and return only the information I need. I want to run a class method so that each row will be sent through the javascript function and the return value will be recorded in the 'filtered_activity' column. How do I call this javascript function from the model?

Basically, I want to say..

```
def self.filter_data
  leads = Lead.all
  leads.each do |lead|
    response = javascriptFunction(lead.activity)      
    lead.update(filtered_activity: response)
  end
end
```

Thank you!!

Comment: is there a reason you need to use the javascript function? You can parse json with ruby, too.

Comment: Which database? If it has native JSON support then you should be able to do everything inside the database by rewriting your JavaScript function.

Comment: Database is sqlite3 but I'm not sure how to do everything in the database, can look into it though. I can parse it with ruby as well, but the javascript function is long (the 'activity' fields are quite dense) so it will just take some time. Ultimately, each 'activity' has an array of nested objects and I'm cross referencing those object id's to another set of data - these are all events that users performed over years. Clicked links, downloaded papers, watched videos, etc. and I need to compile a list of just what was done and what was the name of the paper, video, link, etc.

Comment: I know your question is how to execute JavaScript from the model, but could you approach it from a different way? What about a controller action that sends an array of activities and ids to a JS file with your function, and then the file sends back an array of filtered activities and ids that you could use to update the models?

Comment: I wound up rewriting the js function in ruby and parsing the json object right in the model. It worked, and just in time for a long weekend. Thanks for guidance, all.